# How to avoid white space in css/bootstrap in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, whitespace

I have a screenshot as shown below which I have replicated in CSS/Bootstrap. It will look same both in mobile and desktop view.

[image]

I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6pa4ed0/4/embedded/result/) for the upper portion of the screen-shot which has search-icon(**at the extreme left**) and ellipsis(**at the extreme right**).

I have also created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kqrz13wx/5/embedded/result/) for the bottom portion of the screen-shot which has **2 rows and 4 columns**.

The snippets of HTML code which I have used in order to make the row and search-icon are:

**Row:**

```
 <tr>
     <th scope="col">Name</th>
     <th scope="col" class="number">Number</th>
     <th scope="col" class="table2">Table</th>
     <th scope="col" class="status">Status</th>
 </tr>
```

**Search-form:**

```
   <form class="back">
        <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <input type="text" name="search" class="extand ">
    </form>
```

**Problem Statement:**

The reason why I have created **two separate fiddle** because AS **soon as I add the table row and column code(mentioned in the 2nd fiddle) on my pc, I am seeing the** `WHITE SPACE AT THE EXTREME RIGHT`

**MY QUESTION IS**, on merging those 2 codes(from 2 separate fiddles)  on my pc, somehow I am seeing the **space at the extreme right** on my pc **on mobile view** as shown below(**marked with green arrow**).

I am wondering, what changes I should make in the fiddles above so that I don't see any space at the right.

[image]

Comment: have you tried applying `table-responsive` to the table's classes? [More here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#responsive-tables)

Comment: Nope, I haven't tried. Where should I be using it ?

Comment: See the link I added! I will also write a short answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You table simply isn't responsive.
[Bootstrap 4 provides utilities for responsive tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#responsive-tables):

> ## Responsive tables
>
> Responsive tables allow tables to be scrolled horizontally with ease. Make any table responsive across all viewports by wrapping a `.table` with `.table-responsive.` Or, pick a maximum breakpoint with which to have a responsive table up to by using `.table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}`.
>   […]

You can also find this example:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It perfectly makes sense. I added `table-responsive` in my code and its working perfectly fine. Now, I can't see any space at the right.

Comment: @user5447339 great! I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Also, I have a similar question. I am wondering what changes should I make in the code so that **the design which I have attached above should look exactly the same as mobile design**.

Comment: When the [2nd fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kqrz13wx/5/embedded/result/) takes the mobile view, I can see a line break in the 1st column.

Comment: In the fiddle, unfortunately the mobile view is not working properly for some reasons.

Comment: @user5447339 well, for this see Ozan Ertürk's answer. As he states, the padding in youtr cells is not necessary. Let the table handle that by itself — just remove the padding.

Comment: His answer makes sense. The reason why I have used padding because I have the design which I have to replicate. I will try to remove the padding and will see if that works.

Comment: Did you try it out? How does it look?
Remember to mark the correct answer, if it has solved your problem :)

Comment: I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuchmbq5/7/embedded/result/). I am wondering what changes I should so that I can avoid the line break problem.

Comment: @user5447339 padding is space without content, so remove `.table td.left {
 padding-right: 32%;
}` this. Let the table cell calculats its own width, that's what responsiveness is for!

Comment: I have a specific design which I have to replicate. If I remove the padding, I won't be able to get the desired design. What should I add if I decided to remove the padding ?

Comment: The design which I am trying to replicate is mentioned in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

```
.table td.left {
     padding-right: 32%; 
}
```

this rule makes your table body overflow. It is not recommended that using padding on table contents. You could consider defining your table width at the beginning.

for example `.table.td{ width:25%; padding:0px;}`

Comment: It makes sense. I made the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuchmbq5/7/embedded/result/) for the rows and column. I am wondering if you can update there. Somehow I can't see mobile view on fiddle.